# What would an inlet look like on a hypersonic aircraft? Would it be fixed or movable?

Tags: inlet, hypersonic

What would an inlet look like on a hypersonic aircraft? Would it be rectangular or like a cone (assymetric). Would it move and if so how?

Comment: If your aircraft is made to fly at only one speed (like the [X-43](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43)) there is no need to have a variable inlet. Optimizing it for only one speed is enough.

Comment: I dont undertsand. Wouldnt you need a movable inlet to compensate for the shockwave changing position

Comment: If your speed don't change, the shockwave position won't change. For example, the [X-51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-51_Waverider) is not design to fly slower than mach 4.5 nor faster than mach 5.1. This speed range is really narrow, thus no need to design an inlet efficient from full stop to high hypersonic speed.

Comment: But doesnt the speed change as you speed up from 0 to your normal speed?

Comment: @LukeJustin, you can't use the same engine across that range anyway. Turbines are useless above around M3, ramjets start at maybe M0.5, are efficient above M2 or so and top at M6 and scramjets start above M3 and only become efficient above M6 or so. Much more reconfiguration than just the inlet.

Comment: @ManuH You said if you speed dont change shcokwave wont change position. But what about the speeds to get up to Mach 5?

Comment: @LukeJustin The X-51 is accelerate to mach 4.5 with a ditchable rocket.

Comment: Also note that all ramjet/scramjets are accelerated via external means (either drop from a mothership like the [Leduc 0.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leduc_0.10), or most impressive the [D-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_D-21)) another engine (such as the [nord 1500 griffon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_1500_Griffon)) or a rocket (such as the [X-43](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-43)).

Comment: I think you may review your question because hypersonic inlet do exist but your question can easily be transformed to include engines combining turbojet engin and a kind of ramjet (e.g. the engine of the Nord 1500 Griffon II or the [J58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_J58#Design) with its by-pass mechanism).